# Comparing two SQL Queries, will these return the same result?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   CustomerShip
LEFT OUTER JOIN
                (SELECT DISTINCT b.ShipSeq AS shipSeq
                 FROM   Orders a,
                        CustomerShip b
                 WHERE  a.OrderId IN (SELECT OrderId
                                      FROM   Orders
                                      WHERE  CustomerId = @CustomerId
                                      AND    OrderType <> 'A')
                 AND    b.CustomerId = @CustomerId
                 AND    b.ShipSeq = a.CustShip
                 AND    OrderStatus <> 'C'
                 GROUP BY b.ShipSeq) i
WHERE  CustomerId = @CustomerId
AND    (Address NOT LIKE '%RETAIL%STORE%')
AND    ShipSeq = i.ShipSeq(+)
ORDER BY ShipTo DESC, OrderDate DESC;
```

I'm confused why there is an `LEFT OUTER JOIN`? Wouldn't this query return the same results?

```
SELECT *
FROM   CustomerShip
WHERE  CustomerId = @CustomerId
AND    (Address NOT LIKE '%RETAIL%STORE%')
ORDER BY ShipTo DESC, OrderDate DESC;
```

I'm relatively new to SQL, but in what case would the first query return additional records that the second query would not?

Comment: I assume this atrocious syntax is Oracle, so I added the tag.  `(+)` is deprecated and you should learn to use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax -- never use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: You are correct, the first query is Oracle....One that I did not write.

Comment: I don't think you have anything as 'i' in the second query 5th line.

Comment: Oops, good eye. Updated second query.

Answer (score 0):

Both queries will return the same set of records from the Customership table but they do not return the same information.

The first query will return all columns from both CustomerShip + the shipseq column from the "i" query. 
The second query will only return CustomerShip columns.

Comment: But if the `ShipSeq` column is in both tables, isn't the data returned the same?

Comment: Is there any circumstance where the value of shipseq from "i" might by empty? Maybe in case orderstatus='C'?

Comment: Yes, `i` if often empty.

Comment: Well, then both queries are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Both the queries return the same output .but the first query is looking for all the shipped orders and checking it with the order table where ordertype <> A (not sure the meaning of this though ) and ensures that the shipped record's order is placed in the orders table

Comment: <> A means not equal to A

Comment: Sorry if it confused you ,I was mentioning the fact that I am not sure of the business behind saying order type is not equal to A .